# if HK is a subgroup for all K, does it imply that H is normal?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

we know that in a group *G*, if *H,K* be subgroups such that H is normal, then the product *HK* is also a subgroup.

does the converse hold?
i.e. if *H* is a subgroup of a group *G* such that for any subgroup *K* of *G*, the product *HK* is a subgroup, can we conclude that *H* must be a normal subgroup?

Comment: i guess that the answer will be negative. i will try to make a group of order p^3, for an odd prime p, and consider a non-normal subgroup of order p in it.

Comment: also i think that if the answer will be positive, working only with the cyclic subgroups as K, will give the result.

Comment: Subgroups with that property are called *permutable* or *quasinormal*. The example you suggest works: see http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Permutable_not_implies_normal